# Flex-lexer: Is using `%option debug` the same as defining `FLEX_DEBUG`

Tags: flex-lexer

When running `flex` on my *.l file with `%option debug` i see `#define FLEX_DEBUG` in the generated scanner file.

Is there any difference between using `%option debug` and just defining `FLEX_DEBUG` by passing `-DFLEX_DEBUG` to gcc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference with the current version of flex. The only thing that `%option debug` does is insert `#define FLEX_DEBUG` into the output file. This is also what is done if `-d` or `--debug` is specified on the flex command-line.

However, there is one important difference: The `FLEX_DEBUG` macro is not documented, so there is no guarantee that the behaviour will not change with future versions. (This is different from the yacc/bison `YYDEBUG` macro, which is documented.)